# What's with empty arrays and generics in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

Ran across an interesting bug earlier today when working with generics in Swift. I figured out a solution, but I'm wondering if anyone can answer why the compiler does not catch something like this. Let me start with a block of code.

```
func doSomething<T>(with array: [T]) {
    type(of: array)     // Optional<Array<Int>>
    array is [Int]      // true 
    array is [String]   // true 
}

var arrayOfInts: [Int] = []
doSomething(with: arrayOfInts)
```

See line 4. Why the heck is that `true`? Am I missing something? Shouldn't the compiler be smart enough to figure out this isn't an array of `String`s? This ultimately led to a bug where a value was set incorrectly due to the empty array assumed to be of the wrong type.

As far as a solution, I went with something along the lines of:

```
if type(of: array).Element.self == Model.self
```

Comment: You _know_ the type of the array's elements; it's T. Simpler: `if T.self == Int.self`

Comment: Also I don't get `Optional<Array<Int>>` for the first line.

Comment: The generic is a red herring! `[Int]() is [String]` is `true`.

Comment: Related bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6192. Note that this is also currently the case with empty sets, empty dictionaries and `nil` optionals.

Comment: Although why do you need to do type casting in a generic function? Surely you just want an overload of `doSomething` that takes a `[Int]`, and another overload that takes a `[String]`?

Comment: Yeah I can see how this might be confusing with this example. In my case I have a delegate method being called by my networking class when an update occurs. I don’t want to create a method for each possible model.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it has nothing to do with the generic. Any empty array answers the `is` question with `true` if the type is an array:

```
[Int]() is [String] // true
[1] is [String] // false
```

It does seem odd; [file a bug](http://bugs.swift.org).